# Android Room: How to return rows from a joined table

Tags: android, join, android-sqlite, android-room, one-to-one

I have the following tables:

```sql
category:
id integer primary key autoincrement;
name text not null;

transaction:
id integer primary key autoincrement;
amount real not null;
category_id integer references category(id);
```

And have the following entity classes

```java
class Category {
    @PrimaryKey int cat_id;
    String name;
}

class Transaction {
   @PrimaryKey int tx_id;

   double amount;

   @ForeignKey(entity = Category.class, parentColumns = "category_id", childColumns = "cat_id")
   int category_id;

   @Embedded Category category;
}
```

When I run the following query, `Transaction.category` is always null

```sql
select t.* from transaction t JOIN category c ON t.category_id = c.cat_id
```

So far, most of the tutorials online don't show how to handle this situation. In fact, it also turns out room inserts the `@Embedded` fields.

How can I structure the entities to make sure a single query to retrieve transactions returns with related categories? The relationship is always one-to-one.

I'm using RxJava and do not want to do second queries. I would like to have a single query return everything because it's displayed in a ReycyclerView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the answer from here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/database-relations-with-room-544ab95e4542 and https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

So basically, the solution is to use the `@Relation` annotation , which can only be used on POJOs only as described here:

Please note this is for 1:1 relationships.

> A one-to-one relationship between two entities is a relationship where
>   each instance of the parent entity corresponds to exactly one instance
>   of the child entity, and vice-versa.
>
> For example, consider a music streaming app where the user has a
>   library of songs that they own. Each user has only one library, and
>   each library corresponds to exactly one user. Therefore, there should
>   be a one-to-one relationship between the User entity and the Library
>   entity.
>
> First, create a class for each of your two entities. One of the
>   entities must include a variable that is a reference to the primary
>   key of the other entity.

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long userId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

@Entity
public class Library {
    @PrimaryKey public long libraryId;
    public long userOwnerId;
}
```

> In order to query the list of users and corresponding libraries, you
>   must first model the one-to-one relationship between the two entities.
>   To do this, create a new data class where each instance holds an
>   instance of the parent entity and the corresponding instance of the
>   child entity. Add the @Relation annotation to the instance of the
>   child entity, with parentColumn set to the name of the primary key
>   column of the parent entity and entityColumn set to the name of the
>   column of the child entity that references the parent entity's primary
>   key.

```java
public class UserAndLibrary {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userOwnerId"
    )
    public Library library;
}
```

> Finally, add a method to the DAO class that returns all instances of
>   the data class that pairs the parent entity and the child entity. This
>   method requires Room to run two queries, so add the @Transaction
>   annotation to this method to ensure that the whole operation is
>   performed atomically.

```java
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
public List<UserAndLibrary> getUsersAndLibraries();
```